# Opening Access database in exclusive mode

Tags: ms-access, vba, vbscript

I'd like to be able to write a script that opens a Access database in exclusive mode so I can refresh the information in it without worrying about other users accessing the database in an inconsistent state. Is there a way to do this using VBA, or through a COM interface using VBScript?

Comment: Don't forget the stick to chase all the users out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this table of OLEDB init properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you should add a "Mode=Share Exclusive" to your connection string.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't know what should happen if any users have the database open when your script starts.  So I chose to check for the presence of a database lock file, and only continue if the lock file doesn't exist.

Here is DoSomethingExclusively.vbs:

```
Option Explicit

Dim strFolder
Dim strMdb
Dim strLckFile
Dim objFSO
Dim appAccess

strFolder = "C:\Access\webforums\"
strMdb = "whiteboard2003.mdb"
strLckFile = "whiteboard2003.ldb"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not (objFSO.FileExists(strFolder & strLckFile)) Then
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strFolder & strMdb, True
    '* do something here; this just adds a row with current time *'
    appAccess.CurrentDb.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('" & CStr(Now()) & "');" 
    appAccess.Quit
    Set appAccess = Nothing
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use any DAO stuff with an OLEDB connection. You have to use ADO.

Comment: Checking for the existence of the LDB file is a poor proxy for whether the database is open or not, because the LDB file can survive a close of the database (e.g., when Access crashes).

Comment: It could be left for non-dangerous reasons, such as the file being in a folder where the users lack DELETE permissions (so the LDB file isn't deleted when all users exit). Attempt to KILL the LDB file. If it errors, somebody is in it; if it succeeds, everybody's out of it.